# right sql query

Tags: linq

I have the following problem. In my database table I have a coloum with  the name ItemDaysNext (the coloumn is an integer). The value is ever null and this is ok....

I would like use this coloumn after for a sort value...

This satement works fine:

```
var query = from item in items
                    let today = DateTime.Today
                    let birthday = item.ItemDate
                    let next = new DateTime(today.Year, birthday.Month, birthday.Day)
                    let next2 = next < today ? next.AddYears(1) : next
                    orderby (next2 - today).Days ascending
                    select item;
```

But I would like use the result from "(next2 - today).Days" into the ItemDaysNext because then I can sort after better a Listbox because I can bind the value...

This statement doesn't work and I become a compiler error message (InvalidCastException)

```
var query = from item in items
                    let today = DateTime.Today
                    let birthday = item.ItemDate
                    let next = new DateTime(today.Year, birthday.Month, birthday.Day)
                    let next2 = next < today ? next.AddYears(1) : next
                    orderby (next2 - today).Days ascending
                    select new { ItemDaysNext = (next2 - today).Days };
```

How can I make the correct Query????

Best regards for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can replicate something similar to your problem is making the column "ItemDate" nullable and putting a null value in the database. This is easily fixed by assigning birthday to something else when null eg: line 3 `let birthday = item.END_DATE ?? DateTime.MaxValue`